# Can't return from standby mode when machine goes to timed sleep

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, standby

Dell XPS M1530 running Vista SP1. Recent problem. When machine automatically enters standy, it will not resume. even after a hard reset. A brief power light and then nothing but fan noise. Black screen, no power light.

Actually when it goes to auto-standby ,it doesn't go all the way. All leds are off and screen is black but fan is going. I do a hard power down,  remove the battery and wait a few hours before replacing. Machine will then reboot.

No problem when I manually sleep the machine. No problem with hibernate. Hybrid sleep turned off.

Problem *only* on Automatic timed mode sleep (which I have turned off for now).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the **Advanced Configuration and Power Interface** within the Device Manager. The ACPI can cause a lot of unexpected issues when the batteries starting to die. Also try what **TuxRug** said it'll help narrow down the problem.

[image]

Comment: I know this screen shot is from a Windows XP machine, but its the same on Vista.

Comment: Here's what I got with the Pwercfg queries. Last one would not work.

Comment: Looks like I have to post separate results due to comment length restrictions.
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b  (Dell Recommended) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

Comment: OK - how do I post these results in a readable manner? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I've reposted a different hopefully more coherent statement of the problem.